# android showing crunching failed in windows 10

Tags: android, image, gradle, drawable

Error showing after adding after converting image to nine patch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYVaQ.png)

Given code below is my build.gradle (app) code where i added aaptOption and other tag .After that also still showing error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shailajakori.customdialogassignment1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled false
    }

    aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled=false;
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: set `useNewCruncher =false`

Comment: add `aaptOptions` within `android` tag

Comment: aaptOptions is already inside android tag .Thanks for response